# How to select faces around a face, but not the face itself?

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces, selection-tools

I have these faces selected:
[image]

What I want to do is, to select 4 faces surrounding each of these faces, but not 'these faces'
[image: this picture sort of describes what I'm trying to say]

P.S. sorry if what I'm trying to say is a bit unclear, I don't really know how to say it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if there's a direct way, and if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> (invert selection) it will also select some unwanted faces. But you can select one of the desired faces and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> > *Similar > Perimeter*:

[image]